# Spring boot maven modular build

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I'm fairly new to both maven and Springboot. Trying to add a rest-module to my project.

Im getting: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.3.4.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project rest: Execution default-cli of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.3.4.RELEASE:run failed: Unsupported class file major version 60 -

This is my child pom.xml

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>it1901.infectiontracer</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
 <artifactId>rest</artifactId>
   <dependencies>
 <dependency>
        <groupId>it1901.infectiontracer</groupId>
        <artifactId>core</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
   <dependency>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
      <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <scope>test</scope>
  <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-test-autoconfigure</artifactId>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <version>5.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.7.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.7.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
        <version>5.7.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jgit</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.jgit</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.0.201906121030-r</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.spotbugs</groupId>
                <artifactId>spotbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
         <plugin>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
  </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

this is my module-info.java

```
module infectiontracer.rest {
 requires infectiontracer.core;
  requires java.annotation;
  requires spring.beans;
  requires spring.context;
  requires spring.web;
  requires spring.boot;
  requires spring.boot.autoconfigure;

 }
```

and my Application class

```
 package infectiontracer.restserver;
 import java.util.Arrays;

 import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
 import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
 import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
 import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
 import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

           @SpringBootApplication
            public class InfectionTracerApplication {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(InfectionTracerApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner(ApplicationContext ctx) {
    return args -> {

        System.out.println("Let's inspect the beans provided by Spring Boot:");

        String[] beanNames = ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames();
        Arrays.sort(beanNames);
        for (String beanName : beanNames) {
            System.out.println(beanName);
        }

    };
   }

 }
```

Anyone who can point me in the right direction?

Upon doing mvn clean install in the root directory, it installs and compiles with success.
But I cant seem to start the server with the mvn spring-boot:run (in the root of my spring-boot pom.xml)

Maven version: 3.8.2
Java version: 16.0.2

EDIT: Removed some depencendies and edited in the error message, and removed picture, as mentioned per comment.

parent pom.xml:

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>


<groupId>it1901.infectiontracer</groupId>
<artifactId>parent</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<properties>
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-                                  
  8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>16</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>16</maven.compiler.target>
 </properties>
 <dependencies>
    <!-- javafx -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
        <version>16</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
        <version>16</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- junit testing with jupiter -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.7.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.7.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
        <version>5.7.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- test javafx with TextFX -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>testfx-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.16-alpha</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>testfx-junit5</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.16-alpha</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.8</version>
    </dependency>
  <dependency>
  <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
  <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
  <version>1.3</version>
   </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jgit</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.jgit</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.0.201906121030-r</version>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies>
   <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <release>16</release>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M5</version>     
        </plugin>
         <!-- Jacoco test -->
        <plugin>
               <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
               <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>0.8.7</version>
               <executions>
                    <execution>
                      <id>jacoco-prepare-agent</id>
                      <phase>process-test-classes</phase>
                      <goals>
                       <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
       <!-- Skip this phase if unit tests are skipped -->
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jacoco-report</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        <!-- Run the checkstyle code quality tool -->
            <plugin>
             <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>3.1.2</version>
              <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.puppycrawl.tools</groupId>
                     <artifactId>checkstyle</artifactId>
                     <version>9.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <configuration>                 
      <configLocation>google_checks.xml</configLocation>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
                    <failsOnError>true</failsOnError>
                    <linkXRef>false</linkXRef>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                    <id>checkstyle-check</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>check</goal>
                    </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
         <!-- Run the spotbugs code quality tool -->
            <plugin>
              <groupId>com.github.spotbugs</groupId>
              <artifactId>spotbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.4.1</version>
                <configuration>
                  <xmlOutput>false</xmlOutput>
                  <htmlOutput>true</htmlOutput>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                    <id>spotbugs-check</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>check</goal>
                    </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>       
        <plugin>
           <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
         <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.6</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
   </build>
    <modules>
    <module>core</module>
    <module>fxui</module>
    <module>rest</module>
    </modules>

    </project>
```

Comment: Seems like an issue with the maven version. What version are you using on your machine?

Comment: @Tacolibre 3.8.2 - too old/new version?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @AlexanderBrandhaug Maven 3.8.2 is a recent version. Latest is 3.8.3

Comment: What is your Java version? Run `mvn -v` and [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69745939/edit) the question and add it.

Comment: 1. your dependencies are a mess (mixing different versions of Spring and Spring Boot, this will blow up at some point). 2. Your dependencies (as posted here) aren't even valid (at least the xml structure isn't). 3. You are using a java version that isn't supported.

Comment: The actual problem is your javafx dependency which is for java16 which you, judging by the erorr, aren't using.

Comment: Updated the post according to your comments.

Comment: Solution: The version numbers of the dependency's where old and out of date. I added new version number from maven central and it is now working as intended (also cleaned up alot in my pom-files, as they where a mess, as stated before).